# SQL query works with one select but with two selects returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a sql syntax. When im using just one filter everything works just fine, but with more than one mysql returns 0 results. I would appreciate your help.

```
select 
p.products_id, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_price, pd.products_name
from
products_description pd, 
products_to_categories p2c,
products p left join  manufacturers  m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id   
where 
p.products_id in (SELECT p2pef.products_id 
                  FROM products_to_products_extra_fields p2pef
                  WHERE 
               // filter no 1
               (p2pef.products_extra_fields_id = '102' and p2pef.products_extra_fields_value = 'tak') 
               // filter no 2
               and (p2pef.products_extra_fields_id = '94' and p2pef.products_extra_fields_value = 'tak')
              // no xx
                   )
and p.products_status = '1'
and p.products_id = pd.products_id
and p.products_id = p2c.products_id
and pd.language_id = '4'
and p2c.categories_id = '26'

group by p.products_id
```

----edit

I think that i moved somehere, but this syntax returns just one record instead of many more:

```
select 
p.products_id, pd.products_name
from
products_description pd, 
products_to_categories p2c,
products p
where 
EXISTS (SELECT p2pef.products_id 
                  FROM products_to_products_extra_fields p2pef
                  WHERE p2pef.products_extra_fields_id = '78' 
                 and p2pef.products_extra_fields_value = 'tak' 
                   and p.products_id = p2pef.products_id )
and 
EXISTS (SELECT p2pef.products_id 
                  FROM products_to_products_extra_fields p2pef
                  WHERE p2pef.products_extra_fields_id = '94' 
                  and p2pef.products_extra_fields_value = 'tak'
                    and p.products_id = p2pef.products_id )          


and p.products_status = '1'
and p.products_id = pd.products_id
and p.products_id = p2c.products_id
and pd.language_id = '4'
and p2c.categories_id = '26'

group by p.products_id
```

Comment: ask yourself: is it possible that `products_extra_fields_id` is equal to 102 and to 94 in one row?

Comment: Seems like you want to use an OR instead of an and, the same field can't be 2 different things, p2pef.products_extra_fields_id will never be 102 AND 94

Comment: I think because "products_extra_fields_id" cannot contain both values at same time try with an "or" instead of "and"

Comment: I agree it appears you need an OR instead of AND

Comment: Or woks bot i nedd to filter both values in the same time. I edited more question with new solution.

Comment: The question remains.  if you're expecting more records: is it because you want both when a record has an extra field of 78 OR 94 with a value of tak or only when both exists should a record show (as you now have)?  If either then `an` or or an in `p2pef.products_extra_fields_id in ('78','94')` makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same query, I replaced the AND with the OR, give it a try

Edit: using information from the comments, then use and IN, it's way easier as the path you're taking

```
SELECT
p.products_id, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_price, pd.products_name
FROM
products_description pd, 
products_to_categories p2c,
products p 
LEFT JOIN manufacturers  m ON p.manufacturers_id = 
m.manufacturers_id   
WHERE
p.products_id IN (SELECT p2pef.products_id 
              FROM products_to_products_extra_fields p2pef
              WHERE 
           // filter no 1
           (
           p2pef.products_extra_fields_id IN ('94', '102') 
           AND p2pef.products_extra_fields_value = 'tak'
           ) 

               )
AND p.products_status = '1'
AND p.products_id = pd.products_id
AND p.products_id = p2c.products_id
AND pd.language_id = '4'
AND p2c.categories_id = '26'

GROUP BY p.products_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to search for two different `p2pef.products_extra_fields_id` at the same time time. Try using `OR` between your filters instead of `AND`. Let me know if it helps you.